# Username is Email Address

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I did this for change the username to email:

1. Add New User in carbon where username is email.
2. In "Select Roles of the User", select all.
3. After that in [API-MANAGER]/repository/conf in the file **deployment.toml** add this line

deployment.toml

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
```

And edit:

```
[super_admin]
username = "EmailAddress"
password = "somepassword"
create_admin_account = true
```

Where email address is the same email and password to add in carbon.

4. Restart the server.

Check in https://localhost:9443/carbon, https://localhost:9443/publisher and https://localhost:9443/devportal. 
And NO problem to sign in, **but** in terminal I have this:

> ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.17.0.1:9711.
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.17.0.1:9711.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:145) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to data receiver :/172.17.0.1:9711
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:50) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor267.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryEventSender.processResponse(BinaryEventSender.java:163) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:44) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
>       ... 6 more

**Is a problem?
In case is a problem affect in production ambient?
How fix?**

### Edit: After to read the problem is:

In username the character **@** is **not possible to use**

So, change my cuestion: If possible to create a username similar to **something@something.com** or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified user name for the [super_admin] configuration as follows.

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin@gmail.com@carbon.super"
```

Also, you need to do the following configurations as well to the deployment.toml file.

```
[user_store.properties]
UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx = "^[\\S]{3,30}$"
UsernameJavaScriptRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0–9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0–9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
UsernameJavaRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0–9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0–9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"

[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"
username = "admin!wso2.com!carbon.super"
```

In [APIM_HOME]/repository/conf/claim-config.xml file, change the attribute of the username claim as below.

```
    <Claim>
        <ClaimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/username</ClaimURI>
        <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
        <AttributeID>mail</AttributeID>
        <Description>Username</Description>
    </Claim>
```

Thanks

Menaka